# Crawler de Tweets

Tags: python, web-crawler, twitter-api

estou utilizando a API fornecida pelo tweeter junto ao python para buscar determinados tweets.

O problema é que desejo **visualizar os tweets recebidos pela pessoa e não os tweets enviados por ela**  porém, não estou tendo sucesso, apenas visualizo os tweets da página em questão. segue código:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

access_token = "minhas credenciais da API para devs do TT"
access_secret="minhas credenciais da API para devs do TT"
consumer_key="minhas credenciais da API para devs do TT"
consumer_secret="minhas credenciais da API para devs do TT"


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# The Twitter user who we want to get tweets from
name = "skyresponde"
# Number of tweets to pull
tweetCount = 5

# Calling the user_timeline function with our parameters
results = api.user_timeline(id=name, count=tweetCount)

# foreach through all tweets pulled
for tweet in results:
   # printing the text stored inside the tweet object
   print(tweet.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está recebendo os tweets enviados pela pessoa, porque é isso que o método `.user_timeline()` faz...

No tweeter não existe enviar tweets **para alguém**. O que existe é *mentions* ou *direct message*.

Para achar direct message, pode usar:

```
for m in api.direct_messages():
    print(m)
```

Para achar os mentions, você precisa localizar com `search`:

```
for t in api.search(q='@skyresponde', count=100):
    print(t)
```

Lembrando que, para usar este último, não é preciso ser usuário do tweeter, pois os tweets são públicos, então você pode usar um `AppAuthHandler` ao invés de `OAuthHandler` se quiser, é muito mais rápido.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado !!

Comment: Sabe me informar como consigo fazer para formatar esses tweets? sejam eles pra um notepad ou algo do genero? sem todas as especificações, apenas o tweet em si?

Comment: `api.search()` retorna objetos do tipo `SearchResult` - para pegar o texto do tweet é só usar o atributo `text`, por exemplo: `print(t.text)`